# По поводу чекера mail.ru

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, mail.ru

В Post запросе есть такой вот токен под названием `act_token`.
Вопрос: как его генерировать?

Дальше, в этом же запросе, есть строка `page` внутри это `https://e.mail.ru/messages/inbox?authid=keveo8lp.a1c&back=1&from=mail.login&x-login-auth=1` каждый раз элемент `keveo8lp.a1c` меняется вопрос:
какой шаблон у этого элемента(или можно просто использовать `https://e.mail.ru/login`?).
И вообще это обязательные параметры?

Comment: Что такое чекер?

Comment: @hedgehogues что-то что проверит првильность логина и пароля в данном случае через попытку авторизоваться

Comment: А это значение токена точно не в форме авторизации находится?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в какой момент возникает этот запрос. Откуда берётся токен. Вы хотите понять, как происходит авторизация?

Comment: Мне кажется вам стоит посмотреть документацию по [Mail.Ru API](https://api.mail.ru/docs/guides/restapi/)

Comment: @hedgehogues Да хочу понять как сделать вообще ибо первый раз таким занимаюсь. "Откуда берётся токен" - при вводе логина и пароля тип он выдается на каждую сессию насколько я понял

Comment: @Serg Bocharov
Да довольно интересно было бы посмотреть как через api без прокси прогнать около 10 лямов почт за час хмм...

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть на ваше решение вопроса "около 10 лямов почт за час" на любом стеке )))

Comment: @SergBocharov Я видел программы которые проганяют по 7 лямов за 30 минут но к сожалению исходников нету а сами программы сделаны под игровые сервисы

Comment: Жаль. Хотелось бы увидеть как с помощью бесплатных средств реализовать такое и не попасть в черные списки и баны от провайдеров )))

Comment: чем обусловлено временное окно в час? если API позволяет сделать то что требуется, допустим за сутки, почему бы не воспользоваться решением без костылей? и почему нельзя использовать прокси при запросах к API?

Comment: Довольно сложный вопрос, что конкретно. Человек, судя по всему хочет научиться парсить. Если так, то трассируйте запросы и смотрите, какие хедереы передаются откуда и куда. К сожалению, общего решения нет. Руками делать это за вас довольно долго. Поэтому извиняйте